# How to create this table using the same format as in the MWE?

Tags: tables

Using the layout as below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{ colspec = {Q[l, mode=math] Q[c, si={table-format=-1.4}]},
                  row{1}  = {guard, mode=text},
                 row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                  row{2}  = {abovesep=2pt},
                 row{odd[3-Z]} = {belowsep=0.5ex},
                }
    \toprule
Expression  &   Value   \\
     \toprule
a^2 + b^2   & -1.2345       \\
a^2 + b^2   & -1.2345       \\
a^2 + b^2   & -1.2345       \\
a^2 + b^2   & -1.2345       \\
a^2 + b^2   & -1.2345       \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

How can we create the following table?

```
\documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    
    \begin{document}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Parameter values used in numerical simulations of system.}
\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
 & \beta & \mu & \alpha_{1} & p_{1} & \phi & \xi & \psi & p_{2} & p_{3} & \theta & \alpha_{2} \\
\hline
\hline
State 1  & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.12 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.12 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.1\\
\hline
State 2  & 0.21 & 0.22 & 0.11 & p_{1} & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.12 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to change the format of the second table to match the one of the first, you should provide the code for the second table.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I don't know how to construct a table of this form hence I kindly ask.

Comment: Sorry, your question is very unclear. Where is the first table=? Where we show to reproduce? Your M? What is than your problem?

Comment: @Zarko The image I provided is the table I wish to create. I wish to create it in the "professional" way that you made my other tables(for example, the MWE is the one of your answers to my other questions).

Comment: @Math, please have a look here about the basics: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables .

Comment: THan please reformulate your question and provide code for table  in image. Is this a problem to write this simple code? Don't expect that we will retype code which you already have somewhere ...

Comment: @Math If you don't have the code for the second table, you could at least provide the text of all the cells in your question.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz In your answer, you can write all parameters as "x" and put numerical values as "0".

Comment: @Zarko I dont know how to write the code for the second table..

Comment: @Math It would be less work for us if you provide the text.

Answer (score 1):

Usual help to read introductory text about tables. Also is helpful to read used packages documentation. Package `tabularray` has concise and very clear documentation. It is very worth to read it.

**Edit:**
Ups, I forgot on table caption. Now added ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Parameter values used in numerical simulations of system.}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vline{2-Y}=solid,
             colspec = {l *{11}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}},
             cell{1}{2-Z}  = {guard, mode=math},
             }
        & \beta & \mu   & \alpha_1  & p_1   & \phi  & \xi   & \psi  & p_2   & p_3   & \theta    & \alpha_2  \\
State 1 & 0.2   & 0.2   & 0.12      & 0.11  & 0.1   & 0.11  & 0.1   & 0.12  & 0.11  & 0.1       & 0.1       \\
State 2 & 0.21  & 0.22  & 0.11      & \SetCell{guard, c, $} p_1   
                                            & 0.1   & 0.11  & 0.12  & 0.1   & 0.11  & 0.1       & 0.11      \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]