# Adding a "parameters" row of top of this table?

Tags: tables

Consider the following from: [How to create this table using the same format as in the MWE?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678619/how-to-create-this-table-using-the-same-format-as-in-the-mwe)

```
\documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Parameter values used in numerical simulations of system.}
    \label{tab1}
    \begin{tblr}{@{}cccccccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
     & $\beta$ & $\mu$ & $\alpha_{1}$ & $p_{1}$ & $\phi$ & $\xi$ & $\psi$ & $p_{2}$ & $p_{3}$ & $\theta$ & $\alpha_{2}$ \\
    \midrule
    State 1  & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.12 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.12 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.1\\
    State 2  & 0.21 & 0.22 & 0.11 & $p_{1}$ & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.12 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Using the MWE(keeping its format/layout), how can we add a extra row like shown below? (PLEASE IGNORE THE CELLS IN THE IMAGE BELOW).
[image]

Comment: If you show code from other people's answers in your question, you should link back to where you got the code from. Content on this site is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\SetCell[c=11]{}` to merge several cells into one:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Parameter values used in numerical simulations of system.}
    \label{tab1}
    \begin{tblr}{@{}cccccccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    & \SetCell[c=11]{} Parameters\\
    \toprule
     & $\beta$ & $\mu$ & $\alpha_{1}$ & $p_{1}$ & $\phi$ & $\xi$ & $\psi$ & $p_{2}$ & $p_{3}$ & $\theta$ & $\alpha_{2}$ \\
    \midrule
    State 1  & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.12 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.12 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.1\\
    State 2  & 0.21 & 0.22 & 0.11 & $p_{1}$ & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.12 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you align the numerical values at the decimal points?

Comment: @Math Use the `siunitx` library

Comment: How would I implement it in your code?

Comment: @Math You can use it in the same way as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678619/36296

Comment: It wasn't shown in your answer.

Comment: @Math Your question did not ask for decimal alignment and with only a single row of numbers it makes no sense to use it.

Comment: It is natural to have it done(see answer below). There are two rows of numbers

Comment: @Math Then please go ahead and accept Οὖτις's answer!

Comment: I outlined why his answer wasn't suitable if you bothered to read the comment. I don't see why asking for decimal point alignment is causing such an issue but whatever. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

This is another approach using a normal `tabular`.

I added a shortened `\cmidrule` below `Parameters` and I used the `siunitx` package to align your numerical values at the decimal point.
[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Parameter values used in numerical simulations of system.}
    \label{tab1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c*{11}S[table-format=1.2]@{}}
    \toprule
             &\multicolumn{11}{c}{Parameters}                                                                                                         \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-12}
             & {$\beta$} & {$\mu$} & {$\alpha_{1}$} & {$p_{1}$} & {$\phi$} & {$\xi$} & {$\psi$} & {$p_{2}$} & {$p_{3}$} & {$\theta$} & {$\alpha_{2}$} \\ \midrule
    State 1  & 0.2       & 0.2     & 0.12           & 0.11      & 0.1      & 0.11    & 0.1      & 0.12      & 0.11      & 0.1        & 0.1            \\
    State 2  & 0.21      & 0.22    & 0.11           & {$p_{1}$} & 0.1      & 0.11    & 0.12     & 0.1       & 0.11      & 0.1        & 0.11           \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you extend the line below parameters all the way to end of $\alpha_2$?

Comment: Sure, this shortening is achieved by `(lr)` in `\cmidrule(lr){2-12}`. `l` is for shortening the left end, `r`for shortening the right end. In your case you want to delete the `r` or both.

Comment: In the same line as "Parameters" at the very right end.

Comment: Yes, just noticed!

Comment: This is nice but unfortunately it exceeds my page margins. Sam's answer below is ideal after comparing both but I appreciate your time!

Comment: You could modify the space between columns by setting e.g. `\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}`. I assume something similar is automatically done for `tblr` environments.