# Decimal point alignment?

Tags: tables, alignment

How can we achieve decimal point alignment from: [Adding a "parameters" row of top of this table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678634/adding-a-parameters-row-of-top-of-this-table):

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Parameter values used in numerical simulations of system.}
    \label{tab1}
    \begin{tblr}{@{}cccccccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    & \SetCell[c=11]{} Parameters\\
    \toprule
     & $\beta$ & $\mu$ & $\alpha_{1}$ & $p_{1}$ & $\phi$ & $\xi$ & $\psi$ & $p_{2}$ & $p_{3}$ & $\theta$ & $\alpha_{2}$ \\
    \midrule
    State 1  & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.12 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.12 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.1\\
    State 2  & 0.21 & 0.22 & 0.11 & $p_{1}$ & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.12 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try to replace the column definition `c` by `S` for the relevant columns?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Nope, how would I do that?

Comment: Erh, replace the relevant `c`'s in `{@{}cccccccccccc@{}}` with relevant `S[....]`'s, please consult the `siunitx` manual for details.

Comment: You really should familiarize yourself with how to typeset tabular material. That said, you might need to replace `Parameters` by `{{Parameters}}` to keep `siunitix` from parsing this word.

Comment: @daleif I had a look but don't understand how I can apply it to this table

Comment: For example replace the second `c` in that list with `S[table-format=1,2]` and make sure to use `{$\beta$ }` as the header.

Comment: See the examples in the `tabularray` manual section 5.7

Comment: This is duplicate to your previous question to which you receive answer which solve your problem.